# liferay-ui:search-container with model-context, inputs hidden

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-aui

```
<aui:form action="<%=url %>" method="post" name="fm">

         <aui:model-context bean="<%=bean %>" model="<%=MyBean.class %>" />

         <aui:input name="attribute1" />

</aui:form>
```

From this code i was expected my form inputs were populated by model-context. But in my jsp the form inputs are all hidden and i can see just the labels of each ones.

The liferay service layer is implemented on an isolated portlet plugin and on each portlet that needs service implementation i added the dependency.

If i try to add input type manually it appears, but just on input text type. If i have a boolean attribute and i specify type="checkbox" on the specific input, no values are set to inputs.

Comment: I don't see any search container tags in the code snippet you posted. Did you mean the aui tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meant search container with model-context implementation used to valorize inputs type and value automatically. The inputs were hidden 'cause to missing namespace definition in service.xml. Problem solved